# how do this simple batch rename in bash shell?

Tags: file, bash, syntax, rename

I'm trying to rename all files that are of `*_[m|f].txt` to `*.txt`.
If an instance of `_[m|f]` appears in the file name, we can assume it always
appears right before the `.txt` extension.

Examples:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|        input          |       output        |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| hello_hi_wefwef_f.txt | hello_hi_wefwef.txt |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ya_yo_sup_m.txt       | ya_yo_sup.txt       |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

I am currently trying this:

```
for i in *_[m|f].txt ; do
   mv "$i" "${i/-_[m|f].txt/.txt}"
done
```

but it's complaining there is no | operator for regex. Is there a simple way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your script like this:

```
for i in *_[mf].txt; do
   mv "$i" "${i/_[fm]\.txt/\.txt}"
done
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick, though for some reason we don't need the second \. i changed it to . instead

Comment: You're welcome. Please change it accordingly to make it work.